# ListView inside ModalBottomSheet in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to put a listView inside ModalBottomSheet in flutter and I want there to be a divider in the top of the ModalBottomSheet that doesn't move when the listView moves. And I keep getting an error

here is what I am trying to do:

ModalBottomSheet(

-Container(),  // which shouldn't scroll

-ListView(),  // should scroll

)

tried:

- to make ModalBottomSheet.isScrollControlled = false

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**BottomModalSheet**

```
 Widget _showModalBottomSheet() => DraggableScrollableSheet(
        expand: false,
        key: UniqueKey(),
        initialChildSize: 0.7,
        maxChildSize: 0.9,
        minChildSize: .5,
        builder: (context, controller) => Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 59,
              color: Colors.cyanAccent,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                controller: controller,
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    40,
                    (index) => Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color:
                          index.isEven ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

**And Use**

```
 await showModalBottomSheet(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          isDismissible: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => _showModalBottomSheet(),
        );
```